# Visual Studio Code with GitHub Issue

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I recently wanted to start getting into python programming. I decided to follow some video tutorial series on youtube which told me to download Microsofts Visual Studio Code. After I had installed it I kind of ran into an issue, when I go to the GitHub window through the sidebar It shows 5k changes and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQAfX.jpg) error message pops up and the full page looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcHOS.jpg).

I don't know how GitHub works but I do have an [account](https://github.com/C1rcu1tB04rd) (with nothing on there) and want to start using it sometime. I am assuming [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcHOS.jpg) is not the way it is meant to show up. Can someone please tell me why this is happening and how to fix it. (btw I am not logged in to GitHub on my computer in any way if that is how it works but I do have git installed)

And while I am here, does anyone know a guide or a tutorial video on how git works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have "initialised" a git repository in `~/`, and now it is tracking everything under that folder.

To undo this goto `~` (aka HOME) and delete the folder called `.git`.

There's the [Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) you can use to read up on Git.